# I want to make this calculation using java

Tags: java

This is the equation
(input/750)*6
here, whatever value i enter as an input, it will divided by 750, then multiplied by 6
this is the sample of the code i wrote for the calculation

```
    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    String r=textFieldInput.getText();
                    int u=Integer.parseInt("750");
                    String z1 = r / u *6; /*on this line, i'm getting this error "The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int" */

                    textField.setText(z1);

                }catch(Exception ei) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input: Please Enter Number");
}
```

please where do i go from here?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong! Sorry, but you're coding without thinking. Look at the error message critically and then try to make the trivial correction required.

Comment: `String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(r) / u *6)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: no he should parse `r` into an int or double. `double doubleR = Double.parseDouble(textFieldInput.getText());`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels true, i oversaw that one, but he has to cast back to string afterwards as well

Comment: `String z1 = r / u *6;` !!! You need to understand that `String` and `Integer` are different types. For String `+` operator means concatenation whereas for Integer it means addition

Comment: You mean int don't confusing him with the Class Integer.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `String r = textFieldInput.getText();` you define `r` as a String and then in `String z1 = r / u *6;` you try to do math operations with it. You have to make `r` an integer:

```
int r = Integer.parseInt(textFieldInput.getText());
```

---

Another thing I saw in your code is the line `int u = Integer.parseInt("750");`. You can just write `int u = 750;` or like you did with the `6` in `String z1 = r / u * 6;` you can just write `String z1 = r / 750 * 6;` and not use the variable `u`.

---

And finally, you can't get a String directly from doing math operations, the variable `z1` has to be an integer:

```
int z1 = r / u * 6;
```

or you have to convert the equation into a String:

```
String z1 = Integer.toString(r / u * 6);
```

But sometimes the result might be a decimal, not an integer, but this code willround the result down. If you want the decimal result, then you can write:

```
String z1 = Double.toString((double) r / u * 6);
```

> The `(double)` casts `r` from an integer to a decimal so you can get a decimal result from this equaltion.

---

An additional note is that 750 / 6 = 125, so you can simplify the expression to be:

```
String z1 = Integer.parseInt(r / 125);
```

And if you want the result to be decimal, just write:

```
String z1 = Double.toString(r / 125.0);
```

> `125.0` is considered a decimal so the result will be a decimal.

---

The simplest form of this code would be:

```
JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            int r = Integer.parseInt(textFieldInput.getText());
            String z1 = Integer.toString(r / 125);
            //If you want the decimal result, replace the line above with:
            //String z1 = Double.toString(r / 125.0);
            textField.setText(z1);
        }catch(Exception ei) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input: Please enter a  number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try{
               textField.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(textFieldInput.getText())*0.008));
            }catch(Exception ei) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input: Please Enter Number");
}
```

Comment: thank you guys, for your answers. i understand this line textField.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(textFieldInput.getText())*0.008)); but i don't understand this 0.008, is it a conversion ? and how do i do for other numbers? once again thank you very much.. i'm still a starter in java, and the only way i can improve myself is by doing some works and asking professionals like you guys for directions.....

Comment: @Jblaq what is 6 / 750?

Comment: okay, i gat it. you guys are a pretty hash though: but thank you all very much for your assistance, i warmly appreciate it